# Mobile pixels are different than desktop pixels?

Tags: html, mobile

I'm used to develop for desktop computers (10''+ inchs).
I'm trying to make a web site to be used ONLY on mobile.

My doubt is the following: 
I tried to create a a simple large 500x500px.

I tried the resulting page on both Chrome emulated "Nexus 5" (1920x1080 , pixel ration 3) and on real Nexus 5. Same result: in both cases the div is much larger than the screen itself.

I guess this has to do with pixel ration. but I don't understand the link.
Any clue?

thanks in advance

Comment: it might help to use %'s for mobile development instead of flat `px`, and can you post some code to explain your situation better?

Comment: In the end I'm using jQuery mobile (liquid layout grid). I will investigate further for media queries if needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are developing websites for mobile (especially coming from a desktop background), it is recommended that you use [HTML boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) as a starting point.  There are important and subtle differences for mobile, not to mention edge cases arising from cross-browser issues.

For this specific problem, I suspect that you just need to set set the [`viewport` meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag), and the image will appear correctly sized:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```